# postgresql not a valid value for receiver

Tags: receiver, otel

Error: failed to get config: cannot unmarshal the configuration: 1 error(s) decoding:

- error decoding 'receivers': unknown type: "postgresql" for id: "postgresql" (valid values: [jaeger kafka opencensus prometheus zipkin otlp hostmetrics])
  2024/03/13 08:50:44 collector server run finished with error: failed to get config: cannot unmarshal the configuration: 1 error(s) decoding:
- error decoding 'receivers': unknown type: "postgresql" for id: "postgresql" (valid values: [jaeger kafka opencensus prometheus zipkin otlp hostmetrics])

Why is postgresql not a valid type for a receiver in the OTEL collector?
This is the example config from the github, where the receiver is clearly named "postgresql":

(https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/blob/main/receiver/postgresqlreceiver/README.md)

Example Configuration
receivers:
postgresql:
endpoint: localhost:5432
transport: tcp
username: otel
password: ${env:POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD}
databases:
- otel
collection_interval: 10s
tls:
insecure: false
insecure_skip_verify: false
ca_file: /home/otel/authorities.crt
cert_file: /home/otel/mypostgrescert.crt
key_file: /home/otel/mypostgreskey.key

How can I fix this?

I tried simply adding a new receiver called postgresql. The pre-reqs mentioned on the github I have fulfilled; I have a user with the "SELECT on pg_stat_database" granted.
this is my otel config receiver:
postgresql:
username: otel
password: otel
collection_interval: 5s
tls:
insecure: true